# unable to find an url status / unable to ping an url (which SSL enabled host) and handle invalid SSL certificates

Tags: java, ssl-certificate

If i execute the below code, I am getting an exception saying that "**unable to find valid certification path to requested target**"

```
String protocol = "https://10.0.100.80/MyAPP/index.html";
java.net.URL obj = new java.net.URL(protocol);
HttpURLConnection httpReq = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
httpReq.setDoOutput(true);
httpReq.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);
httpReq.setRequestMethod("GET");
Date date = new Date();
System.out.println("iStatus: " + httpReq.getResponseMessage());
System.out.println("iCode: " + httpReq.getResponseCode());
```

Exception:

```
Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: 
sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:323)
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:217)
    at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:218)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:126)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:209)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:249)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1185)
    ... 14 more
Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(SunCertPathBuilder.java:174)
    at java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(CertPathBuilder.java:238)
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:318)
    ... 20 more
```

help me to ping an url which is ssl enabled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

handled this scenario using below implementation.

```
public  Map<String,Object> pingSSLEnabledURL(String urlString) throws Exception {
        Map<String,Object> returnMap = null;
        // configure the SSLContext with a TrustManager
        SSLContext ctx = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
        ctx.init(new KeyManager[0], new TrustManager[] {
            new DefaultTrustManager() }, new SecureRandom());
        SSLContext.setDefault(ctx);

        URL url = new URL(urlString);
        HttpsURLConnection conn = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setHostnameVerifier(new HostnameVerifier() {
            @Override
            public boolean verify(String arg0, SSLSession arg1) {
                return true;
            }
        });
        returnMap = getResponseStatus(url, null, conn);

        conn.disconnect();
        return returnMap;
    }

 private  class DefaultTrustManager implements X509TrustManager {
        @Override
        public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] arg0, String arg1)
                throws CertificateException {
        }

        @Override
        public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] arg0, String arg1)
                throws CertificateException {
        }

        @Override
        public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
            return null;
        }
    }

    private  Map<String,Object> getResponseStatus(URL url, HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection,
            HttpsURLConnection httpsURLConnection) throws IOException {
        Map<String,Object> returnMap = new HashMap<String,Object>();

        returnMap.put("PROTOCOL", url.getProtocol());
        returnMap.put("PORT", url.getDefaultPort());
        returnMap.put("HOST", url.getHost());
        returnMap.put("URL", url.getFile()); 

        if (httpURLConnection != null){

            returnMap.put("STATUS_MESSAGE", httpURLConnection.getResponseMessage());
            returnMap.put("STATUS_CODE", httpURLConnection.getResponseCode());

        }
        if (httpsURLConnection != null){

            returnMap.put("STATUS_MESSAGE", httpsURLConnection.getResponseMessage());
            returnMap.put("STATUS_CODE", httpsURLConnection.getResponseCode());
        }

        return returnMap;

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Have this code and see

```
HttpsURLConnection httpReq = (HttpsURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
```

Comment: Then have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9619030/resolving-javax-net-ssl-sslhandshakeexception-sun-security-validator-validatore